# X-axis labels on Seaborn Plots in Bokeh

Tags: matplotlib, bokeh, seaborn

I'm attempting to follow the [violin plot example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/violin.html) in bokeh, but am unable to add x-axis labels to my violins. According to the [Seaborn documentation](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html) it looks like I should be able to add x-axis labels via the "names" argument, however, the following code does not add x-axis labels:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from bokeh import mpl
from bokeh.plotting import show

# generate some random data
data = 1 + np.random.randn(20, 6)

# Use Seaborn and Matplotlib normally
sns.violinplot(data, color="Set3", names=["kirk","spock","bones","scotty","uhura","sulu"])
plt.title("Seaborn violin plot in Bokeh")

# Convert to interactive Bokeh plot with one command
show(mpl.to_bokeh(name="violin"))
```

I believe that the issue is that I'm converting a figure from seaborn to matplotlib to bokeh, but I'm not sure at what level the x-axis labels go in.

I've confirmed that the labels are showing up in matplotlib before conversion to bokeh. I've also tried adding the labels to bokeh after conversion, but this results in a weird plot. I've created an issue for this problem with the bokeh developers [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/2277).

Comment: if you skip bokeh entirely, are the x-labels as you want them?

Comment: yes, but then I lose interactivity.

Comment: understood -- that was just a diagnostic question. good luck getting this straightened out.

Comment: Since Bokeh 12.5 (April 2017), [support for Matplotlib has been deprecated](https://bokeh.github.io/blog/2017/4/5/release-0-12-5/), so `mpl.to_bokeh()` is no longer available. Also see [this Github comment](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6249#issuecomment-299981362) by bryevdv.

Comment: @JoelOstblom I am not sure why you moved this to a comment. The actual answer is that it is no longer possible. That *is* the answer.

Comment: @bigreddot, in case you didn't notice, a moderator, not the post's author, converted the answer to a comment.

Comment: @francescalus thank you, I misinterpreted who performed the move. In any case I still disagree that it was not the best possible answer, for reasons stated

Comment: @bigreddot, I do see your point, but I don't understand the aspects in detail (I saw your answer from the "new answers to old questions" list).  Perhaps a moderator flag on the deleted answer for "un-conversion"?  But I suppose the ideal is an answer which also says, "but this is how you can do something equivalent in later versions..."?

Answer (score 1):

Since Bokeh 12.5 (April 2017), [support for Matplotlib has been deprecated](https://bokeh.github.io/blog/2017/4/5/release-0-12-5/), so `mpl.to_bokeh()` is no longer available.